# Converting dataframe date column to timestamp in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, timestamp

I have a `dataframe` column for the dates that I need to convert to `timestamp`. Right now the data is as follows:

`6      1970/01/01 01:00:12.273928`
`7      1970/01/01 01:00:12.459902`
`8      1970/01/01 01:00:12.569948`
`11     1970/01/01 01:00:14.292992`
`13     1970/01/01 01:00:14.825224`

I have tried the following

```
st = pd.to_datetime(df['StartTime'])
timestamp = datetime.timestamp(st)
print("timestamp =", timestamp)
```

but receive this error

```
TypeError: descriptor 'timestamp' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'Series'
```

Any idea how I can tackle this?

Comment: What is this for? What is the dtype of the column? Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply. St is a series so it can't be passed to timestamp function directly. You need to apply the timestamp function to the elements of the series.

```
st.apply(datetime.timestamp)

6     1.580998e+09
7     1.580998e+09
8     1.580998e+09
11    1.580998e+09
13    1.580998e+09
Name: StartTime, dtype: float64
```

Comment: The column type is `object` but the data are `strings` so it won't work properly.

Comment: Have you tried?  Haven't you already converted the strings to datetimes using pd.to_datetime?